# Solve the following equations (integer solutions )

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, quadratics

$$ax + p = 1341$$
$$by - q = 1341$$
$$x+y = p+q$$
$$6(x+y) =a+b$$
$$ar-p = 6710$$
$$x+r=b$$
I'm Looking for integer solutions for all the variables with the constraint a,b>0. I could reduce this equation further and eliminate a few variables but I am wondering if these equations can be solved efficiently without having to factor 8051. (1341+6710)Thanks

Comment: You should at least take the effort and reduce the system complexity by eliminating some of the variables (e.g. eliminate $p$ and $q$). Simplify the system and edit your post.

Comment: Well I could reduce this to a(x+r) = 8051 which gives a = 83 and x+r = b = 97 or a = 8051 and b =1 but I am trying to solve these equations without having to factor 8051 or for that matter any other number. Thanks @MrYouMath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting $x,p,q,r,b$ from the equations, only one equation is left, namely the third one,
$$
(a^2 + 8051)(a - 6y + 1)=0.
$$
This implies $y=(a+1)/6$, and all solutions are given by
$$
(a,y,x,p,b,q,r)=\left(a,\frac{a+1}{6},\frac{8051-a}{6a}, \frac{a-5}{6}, \frac{8051}{a},\frac{5a + 8051}{6a},\frac{a + 40255}{6a}\right).
$$
For integral solution we need that $a$ is a divisor of $8051$ such that $a\equiv -1 \bmod 6$. This gives the two positive solutions $a=83$ and $a=8051$, and hence the two integral solutions
$$
(a,y,x,p,b,q,r)=(83,14,16,13,97,17,81),
$$
and
$$
(a,y,x,p,b,q,r)=(8051,1342,0,1341,1,1,1).
$$

Comment: Seems like there are multiple solutions. 
(a,r,p,x,q,y,b)=(83, 81, 13,16,17,14,97).

Comment: Looks like you made an error somewhere in your calculation.  @Dietrich

Comment: Which equation does not hold?

Comment: q = -1341. the given equation is by -q = 1341. @Dietrich

Comment: $-q=1341$ is equivalent to $q=-1341$.

Comment: No I meant     by-q =1341 is the given equation where b and y are variables. @Dietrich

Comment: Oh, I see. "You meant by -q that "by-q$. I thought you meant the English word "by".

Comment: $(a=-97\land b=-83\land p=-17\land q=-13\land r=-69\land x=-14\land y=-16)\lor
   (a=-1\land b=-8051\land p=-1\land q=-1341\land r=-6709\land x=-1342\land
   y=0)\lor (a=83\land b=97\land p=13\land q=17\land r=81\land x=16\land
   y=14)\lor (a=8051\land b=1\land p=1341\land q=1\land r=1\land x=0\land y=1342) $ the only solutions for the variable to be integers, solved in Wolfram Mathematica

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, but  $a,b>0$, so the first two are not possible.